# pandas.errors.IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to int

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
df  = pd.read_csv("WorldCupMatches.csv")
print(df.head())
df['Year'].fillna(0) # (What I found on the Internet may be that there is an empty space in the data, and NA is filled with o, but it is still not easy to use.)
df['Year'] = df['Year'].astype(int) # (How to change the data type of a column in a dataframe)
print(df.dtypes)
ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x="Year", y="Total Goals")
plt.show()
# The year column in the data set is an integer, but when it is loaded into the pandas dataframe, it becomes a floating point format. When I want to change the column to an integer (when entering the fourth line of code), it starts to report an error.
```

> [enter image description here][1] [enter image description here][2]
> [enter image description here][3]
>
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Smws8.png   [2]:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se11H.png   [3]:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQm4R.png

Comment: you have non finite values... try `df['Year'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Year'], errors='coerce').astype(int)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have non finite values, try:

```
df['Year'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Year'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
```